# Password hash returns password does not match

Tags: php, password-hash

I have created a password_hash during my signup process and when I come back to login and type the email and password with the help of password_verify it outputs that the password is not matched. To check my query is working I have generated password hash using online tool in this link http://www.passwordtool.hu/php5-password-hash-generator

This is successfully allowing the user to log in but the auto generated hash by the password_hash always failing which means my query is okay. Is there a solution to make the password_hash work properly?

Any help will be useful.
Thanks in advance,

I have tried using static password_hash which looked like $2y$10$3xrOcCz5fewSd90zS7dgseINs1WpD132MtrWjFmG3qSQcNDXpcgbe which is Password@123

Ajax to handle the Signup

```
        $(function() {
            $(".log").click(function() {
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var password = $("#password").val();
                var confirm_password = $("#confirm_password").val();
                var dataString = 'email='+ email + '&confirm=' + confirm;

                if(email=='' ||password=='' || confirm_password=='' || (password !=confirm_password))
                {
                    swal("Sorry !", "Couldn't create your account !", "error");
                }

                else
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "join.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        success: function(){
                            //$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                            //$('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                            swal("Thanks !","Your account is created !"+" "+"Redirecting you to login","success");


                            setTimeout(function () {
                                window.location.href = "login.php"; //will redirect to your blog page (an ex: blog.html)
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Signup Process

```
    require_once('dbconn.php');


    if($_POST)
    {

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $cpassword = $_POST['confirm_password'];
        $hashed = password_hash($cpassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO user_login (user_email, user_password) VALUES (?,?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $hashed);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        if ($result) {
            echo "Successfully Inserted !";
            //echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            //echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("Thanks!","Your account is created !","success");';
            //echo '}, 1000);</script>';

        }

        else{
            echo "Error occurred! ".mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt)." ".mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)." "; 
            $error = mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        }

    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Login

```
        if(isset($_POST['btn_lg'])) {

            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $sql = "SELECT `user_email`, `user_password` FROM `user_login` WHERE `user_email` = ?";

            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s", $email);

            $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $email, $pass);
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) === 1)
            {

                //$row = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

                $hash = $pass;

                //echo $hash;




                if(password_verify($password, $hash))
                {
                    $_SESSION['Logged'] = true;

                    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

                    ?>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            window.location.href="test.php";
                        </script>
                    <?php
                }


                else
                {
                    echo  "The username or password do not match" ;
                }

            }


            else 
            {
                echo "Login Failed ! " .mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt)." ".mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)." ";  
            }

        }
    ?>
```

I expected the login result to be true but the output is false

Comment: What is the length of the password column in your database? is it 60 chars or more? or less?

Comment: What output are you getting from the results of your query?  What is the value of ````$hash```` when you check it?  Why are you re-assigning it to ````$hash````, why not just use ````$pass```` in the ````password_verify call````?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile The database colum for password is Varchar 255

Comment: @jameson2012 Well I was checking whether the Hashed Password from the database is getting outputted. When I take the $hash from the stmt_fetch it outputted nothing. So, I just wanted to check whether the $pass in the bind_result is being outputted. I always getting Password or Email not matching.

Comment: @jameson2012 When I take from the bind_result it is outputting the hashed password from the database still no luck getting the same fail message

Comment: without seeing more output I can't help really. if num_rows is === 1 then there are only three logical conclusions 1)your password is being altered before you hash and store it, 2) your password is being altered before you compare it,3)Your password is genuinely incorrect.  It may be picking up some whitespace somewhere along the way perhaps?  is $_POST['btn_lg'] definitely set?  is $_POST['password'] set?  I can see you passing confirm in your Ajax but not where you're setting these two?

Comment: also it might be useful to see how the login process works ( i.e. where are the details submitted to the login script - I think you've only shown the sign up here)

Comment: @jameson2012 I am doing the login and taking all the login variable in the same page.  Im not using any ajax for that. I have a doubt by the way sorry if im wrong, will there a possibility of having whitespace in the hash while I sign Up in my code?

Comment: "Im not using any ajax for that" regardless, what I'm saying is that there is possibly something wrong with the way your form is submitting so without seeing it we couldn't say.  re The whitespace comment, I don't mean in the hash I mean in the password string that is submitted (I.e. the post variable) -   you are right it's not very likely, but you are using password_verify correctly and if you are sure that you have the right user details from your select then the only logical conclusion is that, somehow, the password string is not being passed correctly

Comment: @jameson2012 So you are recommending me to recheck the way I pass the password from the front end to the back end right I mean the password string ?

Comment: @jameson2012 Are you asking to see the login page form ?

Comment: @jameson2012 hi thanks I found the mistake. Thanks for spotting out. before it was like var dataString = 'email='+ email + '&confirm=' + confirm; then I changed in to var dataString = 'email='+ email + '&confirm_password=' + confirm_password; Now the hashing works perfectly thank you so much for spotting out this error.